# Ng-click don´t work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, controller, angularjs-ng-click

I have this controller.
It´s for a map view on the app Im working on.
For some reason the button I have on the footer is not working. The action on the function is never called...

```
.controller('mapaCtrl', function($scope, $compile, $location) {

    $scope.goPayment = function() {
        $location.path('side-menu/history');
    };


var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.603711, -58.381585);

    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
        var myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
            map: map,
            title: "My Location"
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(myLocation, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,myLocation);
        });
    });


    var contentString = "<div><a ng-click='clickTest()'>Pagar Aqui!</a></div>";
    var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: compiled[0]
    });

  $scope.map = map;

      $scope.clickTest = function() {
    $location.path('side-menu/pay');
  };




})
```

And I have this call on the html

```
<ion-view title="Mapa" id="page13">
<ion-content ng-controller="mapaCtrl">
  <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer-bar align-title="left" class="bar-balanced">
    <button class="button" ng-click="goPayment()">Ver mis pagos</button>
```

On the Button click there is no call to "$location.path('side-menu/history');"

Can you help me?

Comment: Your button is not in the same scope as your controller (which is to say, within the `ion-content` element). You probably want your `ng-controller` on the `ion-view` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button is outside the scope of the controller.
Check your code.

```
<ion-view title="Mapa" id="page13">
<ion-content ng-controller="mapaCtrl">
  <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
</ion-content> <!--controller ends here-->

<ion-footer-bar align-title="left" class="bar-balanced">
    <button class="button" ng-click="goPayment()">Ver mis pagos</button>
```

The button is outside the controller so there's no function to be called.

Comment: Thank you! I spend so much time with this and was so easy fix. Sometimes you just need to talk with the right person. Thanks

Comment: lol I am not the right person. These little things are the hardests to spot

Answer (score 0):

You've set your controller on the "ion-content" tag. Your button element is outside of this tag. Just move your closing tag below the button and it should work.

```
<ion-view title="Mapa" id="page13">
<ion-content ng-controller="mapaCtrl">
  <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
<ion-footer-bar align-title="left" class="bar-balanced">
    <button class="button" ng-click="goPayment()">Ver mis pagos</button>
</ion-content>
```

Or define your controller on a higher-level element.

```
<div ng-controller="mapaCtrl"> 
  <ion-view title="Mapa" id="page13">
    <ion-content>
      <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
    </ion-content>
    <ion-footer-bar align-title="left" class="bar-balanced">
        <button class="button" ng-click="goPayment()">Ver mis pagos</button>
</div>
```